# The cardinality of the union of two infinite sets of equal cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if A is an infinite set and $|A| = |B|$ then $|A| = |A \cup B|$.

I don't know how to get an injection from $A∪B$ to $A$. I thought about considering $A\times B$, but don't see how that could work.

Comment: Don't know how to get an injection from A∪B to A.  I thought about considering AxB, but don't see how that could work.

Comment: @RaziehNoori Could you please put your comment as an answer?

Comment: Why did my question get marked down?

Answer (score 2):

$$|A |\leq|A \cup B|\leq|A| +| B|\leq 2|A |$$
Note that sin $A$ is infinite set so $2|A |=|A |$

Comment: You can't subtract infinite cardinals

Comment: @Belgi  So how does the proof go?

Comment: I edited it, I do not think this has any pro

Comment: I had done it, it was OP request to write it here. see comments :)

Comment: @RaziehNoori But how would I prove this without using cardinal arithmetic?  I want an explicit statement of the two injections.

Answer (score 0):

The equality of $|A|$ and $|B|$, and Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem allows us to reduce to proving $|A|=|A\coprod A|$. This is accomplished by writing $A=\coprod_{S}\mathbb{N}$, and noting $A\coprod A=\coprod_{S}\mathbb{N}\coprod\coprod_{S}\mathbb{N}=\coprod_{S}(\mathbb{N}\coprod \mathbb{N})$, we are reduced to $A=\mathbb{N}$. There is a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\coprod \mathbb{N}$ given by enumerating even and odd numbers.

Comment: I don't know what this symbol means: "∐_S".

Comment: @Ruby Disjoint union, So $\coprod_{S}$ is just taking the Disjoint union of copies indexed by $S$, where $S$ is some set.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the Disjoint union of copies indexed by S".